Vue3/Vitest: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_vnode')
I have a fairly simple composable that renders a Vue component where we specify it on the DOM (defaults to the 'body'). Below is its entire code.
export default function useComponent(Component, { to = 'body' } = {}) {
  const self = getCurrentInstance()
  const exposed = ref()
  const close = () => (
    (exposed.value = null), render(null, document.querySelector(to))
  )

  onUnmounted(close)

  const set = (props = {}, slots = {}) => {
    const vnode = h(Component, { ...props, onClose: close }, { ...slots })
    vnode.key = Math.random()
    vnode.appContext = self.appContext

    render(vnode, document.querySelector(to))

    exposed.value = vnode.component.exposed
    return exposed
  }

  return { set, close }
}

We would like to add tests though, however, nothing seems to be working. For example, the following tests fails with the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_vnode')
 ❯ Object.render node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6617:19
 ❯ Module.render node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.cjs.js:1456:20
 ❯ Proxy.set src/shared/composables/useComponent.js:47:5
     45|     vnode.appContext = self.appContext
     46| 
     47|     render(vnode, document.querySelector(to))
       |     ^
     48| 
     49|     exposed.value = vnode.component.exposed
 ❯ tests/unit/shared/composables/useComponent.spec.js:22:16

The entire Test code:
import { mount, flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils'
import useComponent from '@shared/composables/useComponent.js'
import BaseBanner from '@shared/components/BaseBanner.vue'

describe('composable/useComponent', () => {
  const title = 'This is a title'

  it('should render a success modal', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount({
      template: '<div id="container"></div>',
      setup() {
        const { set } = useComponent(BaseBanner, {
          to: '#container',
        })

        return { set }
      },
    })

    await flushPromises()

    wrapper.vm.set({ title })

    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain(title)
  })
})

